# How to install 'pandas.Series' in spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am using Spyder from anaconda

I am trying to use

```
import pandas.Series.str.split
```

but I get this error

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.Series'
```

I tried

```
conda upgrade pandas
```

did not work

I tried

```
   pip install pandas.Series
```

did not work

I tried

```
 pip install --upgrade --user pandas
```

did not work

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: You are getting it wrong. `pandas` is the module, `Series` is one of its main classes. Please read the pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html?highlight=series#pandas.Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

You can do

```
from pandas import Series

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

But I would stick with `import pandas as pd` which is the de-facto universal standard for this library.